# Equation for a Fair Grading Curve

Tags: calculus, functions

All:

I'm something of an armchair mathematician, but a recent test I gave during a Spanish II class got me thinking about a function that could potentially be considered 'fair', by a certain definition.

## Problem Stated

I wish to find a function $f(x)$ such that $f(M)=100$, $f(m)=50$ and $\frac{\int_m^Mf(x)dx}{M-m}=75$. Assume that $M$ is the class' maximum score (in per cent) and $m$ is the minimum grade (also in per cent) and that $M>m$. The goal of the curve is that $\forall x\in[0, 100]: f(x)>x$.

## Attempt

Given that there are three pieces of information, I would assume that the most elementary curve would be a Quadratic, thus $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$.

From this, we can deduce the following that the antiderivative of the function would be $\frac{ax^3}{3}+\frac{bx^2}{2}+cx+C$. Thus, we can see that $75=\frac{\left|\frac{ax^3}{3}+\frac{bx^2}{2}+cx\right|_m^M}{M-m}$. (Ignore the first pipe in that; I don't know how to make the 'evaluated from' pipe by itself in LaTeX.)

If we solve for $c$ using the first premise of the problem, we find that $c=100-aM^2-bM$. Similarly, if we solve for $b$ using the second premise and the substitution for $c$, we find that $b=\frac{50}{M-m}-a(M+m)$. We could substitute this back in for the evaluation of $c$ and find that $c=100-aM^2-\frac{50M}{M-m}-aM(M+m)$ or $c=100-2aM^2-\frac{50M}{M-m}-aMm$.

At this point, we can rewrite the third premise in terms of just $a$ as $450(M-m)=aM^3+(\frac{50}{M-m}-a(M+m))M^2+(100-2aM^2-\frac{50M}{M-m}-aMm)M-am^3-(\frac{50}{M-m}-a(M+m))m^2-(100-2aM^2-\frac{50M}{M-m}-aMm)m$. After manipulating the expression, we find:
$$a=\frac{175(m-M)}{M^3-M^2m+Mm}$$

Naturally, this implies
$$b=\frac{50}{M-m}-\frac{175(m^2-M^2)}{M^3-M^2m+Mm}$$
and
$$c=25(4-\frac{2M}{M-m}-\frac{7(m-M)(2M-m)}{M-Mm+m})$$

From all of this, I conclude that
$$f(x)=(\frac{175(m-M)}{M^3-M^2m+Mm})x^2+(\frac{50}{M-m}-\frac{175(m^2-M^2)}{M^3-M^2m+Mm})x+25(4-\frac{2M}{M-m}-\frac{7(m-M)(2M-m)}{M^2-Mm+m})$$

### Good News

When looking at the function, there are three points of potential failure: $M^3-M^2m+Mm=0$, $M-m=0$, or $M^2-Mm+m=0$. Since the first and third expressions are merely the same just reduced by a factor of $M$, we can see that this is only two points of potential failure.

The first (and, by proxy, the third) only fails if $\frac{M^2}{M-1}=m$; the second only fails if $M=m$ which is a contradiction since $M>m$ definitionally. The third one introduces a new (non-zero) chance of failure which is that $M=1$.

Ignoring this, we can look at the case where a separate function, $g(x):=\frac{x^2}{x-1}-x$, is equal to $0$. When we do that, we find that it only happens at $x=0$. Naturally, the other point of contention is where $g(x)>x$. When we calculate this, we find that $(g(x)>x)\Leftarrow (x>-x)$. Since $x$ in this equation is representative of $M$ and $M, m\in(0, 100)$, we know that this is true $\forall M: M\geq1$.

Thus, this curve fails to boost grades or is impossible only if $M<1$.

## Question

Do my maths check out? That is, is this an accurate model? Furthermore, are there any glaring errors that I'm missing my *Good News* section?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You do realize that if $m = 75$, then defining $f(m) = 50$ results in $f(75) < 75$ right? Are you further assuming that $m< 50$?

Comment: Ah, that's a very good point. Yes, I suppose that it'd probably be better to say $f(x)\leq x$ and $m\leq50$

Comment: I suppose a more elementary curve would be linear:

$$f(x) = \frac{50}{M-m}(x-m) + 50 = \frac{50}{M-m}(x+M-2m)\\
\begin{align*}
\int_m^M f(x)\ dx &=
\frac{50}{M-m}\left[\frac{x^2}{2}+(M-2m)x\right]_m^M\\
&= 50\left[\frac{M+m}{2} + (M-2m)\right]\\
&= 75(M-m)
\end{align*}$$

Comment: @peterwhy You're right that a more elementary function would be linear, but I also want it to meet the condition that, as I first posed it to myself, 'the continuous mean is 75'. Thus, $\frac{\int_m^Mf(x)dx}{M-m}=75$

Comment: I already showed that the linear $f$ satisfies $\int_m^M f(x)\ dx = 75(M-m)$, i.e. $\frac{\int_m^M f(x)\ dx}{M-m} = 75$.